# fancybox not loading images in WordPress

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, fancybox

I'm converting my html template to WordPress. Fancybox was working fine in my html version, but not in wordpress.

in html version, the fancybox code was:

```
<a href="images/p3.jpg" class="project-img fancybox"></a>
```

and now in WP version:

```
<a href="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>" class="project-img fancybox"></a>
```

& the jQuery:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({

        padding     : 0,
        margin      : 100,
        openEffect  : 'elastic',
        closeEffect : 'elastic',
        openSpeed   : 400,
        closeSpeed  : 400,

        helpers : {
            overlay : {
                css : {
                    'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)'
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

but it is not working for me, when I hover my images, it returns:

```
class="project-img fancybox">
```

I'm not a pro, so could not find any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use function [get_the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail).

You can't pass the_post_thumbnail into href tag.

Comment: but the problem is I have 4 posts in that section & all are dynamically generated by loop. if I use get_the_post_thumbnail(), I have to use parameter ($post_id) & I don't know how to make it dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You are using the incorrect function in `href` attribute. It displays the Featured Image (previously called Post Thumbnails) for the current post, as set in that post's edit screen. This tag must be used within The Loop.

Use [get_the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) instead:

`<a href="<?php get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr ); ?>" class="project-img fancybox"></a>`